# Should the explanatory text come before or after the animations in tech articles?

Tags: online-publication, blog

This question is in regards to curruclum development theory. The medium is blog articles / technical white-papers (accessed online). I often use animations to help drive points home, and I'm curious as to whether the supporting text should come before or after the animation.

Question:  **Should supporting text come before or after animations?**

Bonus question:  **Should supporting text come before or after still images?** (not-animated)

Examples:

---

### Animation before text

[image]
The data moves from the Server to the left router. Then the Left router to the Middle router. Then the Middle router to the Right router. Then the right router to the Server.

---

### Text before Animation

The data moves from the Server to the left router. Then the Left router to the Middle router. Then the Middle router to the Right router. Then the right router to the Server.
[image]

Comment: Will the text be kind of the caption of the animation?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog It will be much more thorough than a typical caption would allow for. I was provided the text above as a very simplified example, but the actual text will be much more involved. For instance, [this](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/osi-model/#osi-layer-23) is the article text for the animation above.  [Here](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/arp/proxy-arp/#proxy-arp-misconfigured-host) is another example, in this example the text is before the animation, but before the text is a still-frame of the animation that I use to introduce the animation.

Comment: I see. Personally, I prefer the _animation before text_ version because looking upwards for a figure is more common, e.g. LaTeX puts figures on the top of the page by default. If you definitely want the reader to read the text before looking on the animation, go for the _text before animation_ version. As long as you stay consistend in the paper, it might be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Before the animation, introduce the graphic.

Below the animation, include a caption.  Your first example has a nice caption but I would format it so it looks more clearly like a caption.

Provide a way to turn off the animation.  It is hard for some people (like me) to focus on the text that follows while the movement is continuing to take place.

Thank you so much for asking.  Animation on the web can drive a person nuts.  On the other hand, it can be helpful in gaining understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Good call about turning it off, but I'm afraid for a simple gif that functionality doesn't exist (without adding cumbersome plugins/extensions to the site). As for the text vs caption, the truth is the explanation is going to be much more involved than what I used in the example. I provided more information in response to @FuzzyLeapfrog in a [comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84819/should-the-explanatory-text-come-before-or-after-the-animations-in-tech-articles#comment-212568) to the original post. Check it out... would love to hear your thoughts!